# Server can't sent message to client

Tags: android, serversocket

I want to create an app in which server and client communicate each other. here the code...

Server Side:

```
 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private ServerSocket serverSocket;
Handler updateConversationHandler;
Thread serverThread = null;
Socket clientSocket;
  private TextView text;
  EditText edit;
  Button b;
  public static final int SERVERPORT = 6000;
  String TimeStamp;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        System.out.println("inside onCreate");

        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        updateConversationHandler = new Handler();
        this.serverThread = new Thread(new ServerThread());
        this.serverThread.start();

        TimeStamp = new java.util.Date().toString();

        b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                try 
                {
                    EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                    String str = et.getText().toString();
                    text.setText(text.getText().toString()+"Me: "+ str +" On "+TimeStamp+ "\n");

                /*
                    BufferedOutputStream bos=new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                    OutputStreamWriter osw= new OutputStreamWriter(bos,"US-ASCII");
                    osw.write(str+" "+TimeStamp);
                    osw.flush();
                    */
                    if(clientSocket==null)
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "null socket", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    else
                    {
                    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream())),
                            true);
                    out.println(str);
                    out.flush();
                    et.setText("");
                    }
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() 
    {
        super.onStop();
        try 
        {
            serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }

 class ServerThread implements Runnable 
 {
     public void run() 
     {
         Socket socket = null;
         try 
         {
             serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
             serverSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
         } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
     }

     while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) 
     {
        try 
        {
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
            CommunicationThread commThread = new CommunicationThread(socket);
              new Thread(commThread).start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

     }
     }
   }
    class CommunicationThread implements Runnable 
    {
        //private Socket clientSocket;
        private BufferedReader input;
        public CommunicationThread(Socket aclientSocket) 
        {
            //this.aclientSocket = clientSocket;
            clientSocket=aclientSocket;
            try {
                //this.input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                this.input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        public void run() 
        {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) 
            {
                try 
                {
                    String read = input.readLine();
                    updateConversationHandler.post(new updateUIThread(read));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class updateUIThread implements Runnable 
    {
        private String msg;
        public updateUIThread(String str) 
        {
            this.msg = str;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            text.setText(text.getText().toString()+"Client: "+ msg +" On "+TimeStamp+ "\n");
        }
    }
```

}

Messages send from client correctly receives to server, Now messages from Server writes to socket but cant read at client.

here the client side:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private Socket socket;
Handler updateConversationHandler;
private static final int SERVERPORT = 5000;
private static final String SERVER_IP = "10.0.2.2";
TextView text;
Button c;
String TimeStamp;

@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

      new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
      TimeStamp = new java.util.Date().toString();


      c=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
      text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
     c.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try 
            {
                EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                String str = et.getText().toString();
                text.setText(text.getText().toString()+"Me: "+ str +"On "+TimeStamp+ "\n");
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                        true);
                out.println(str);
                out.flush();
                et.setText("");
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

}

class ClientThread implements Runnable 
    {

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try 
            {
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
                socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
                CommunicationThread commThread = new CommunicationThread(socket);
                  new Thread(commThread).start();
            } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
               e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

class CommunicationThread implements Runnable 
{
    private Socket clientSocket;
    private BufferedReader input;
    public CommunicationThread(Socket clientSocket) 
    {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
        try {
            this.input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    public void run() 
    {
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) 
        {
            try 
            {
                String read = input.readLine();
                Log.d("msg","readString"+read);
                updateConversationHandler.post(new updateUIThread(read));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

class updateUIThread implements Runnable 
{
    private String msg;
    public updateUIThread(String str) 
    {
        this.msg = str;
        System.out.println("message in updateThread "+msg);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        System.out.println("message "+msg);
        text.setText(text.getText().toString()+"Server: "+ msg +"On "+TimeStamp+ "\n");
    }
}

}
```

The logcat shows:

```
D/gralloc_goldfish(1777): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
W/System.err(1777): java.lang.NullPointerException 
W/System.err(1777):     at    com.example.socketservereg.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:67)
W/System.err(1777):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)

W/System.err(1777):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)

W/System.err(1777):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)

W/System.err(1777):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)

W/System.err(1777):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

W/System.err(1777):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)

W/System.err(1777):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
```

06-17 
 W/System.err(1777): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)

```
W/System.err(1777):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)

W/System.err(1777):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
```

I am a beginner and any help will be appreciated...

Comment: And what is the question? The message sent by your client should not reach the server also as you output on the main ui thread. Please tell if you use emulators/devices. Explain the setup. Which Android version(s) are in use?

Comment: the message from client should reach to server, but server to client doesnt display. and am works on emulaton through port forwarding, like     "redir add tcp:5000:6000" on Android 4.3

Comment: `and am works on emulaton` That is unclear. Do you use two emulators? One for the server and one for the client?

Comment: Could you please explain how all should work?

Comment: yes, two emulators, first run server application and then client on another. both uses the same method for conversation, and it works on client side and not on server side

Comment: there are 2 apps, one for server and another for client. both runs on different emulators. when user touch on send button from client side that message appears on server as well as client too. it works. then server want to reply for that, that doesn't appear on client side

Comment: You did not explain how all your code should work.

Comment: What code is in MainActivity.java:67?

Comment: @Override, this is the 67th line in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the server you use

```
socket.getOutputStream()
```

but it should be

```
clientSocket.getOutputStream()
```

Comment: this line makes client doent run, ie a message "unfortunately client has stopped work"

Comment: Well that was code for the server. What is happening? At which moment/action/code line does this happen? You did not adapt the server code here. Please show what you did. Please post logcat and stacktraces.

Comment: there is no error message actually. if i press the send button on server side the message will appear on server gui but nothing on client(i want it like a chat). I think the problem is with 'onClick()' method, here     'PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                            true);
                    out.println(str);out.flush();et.setText("");'     doesnot seems to work, because if the message send successful the editText set to null. but when i run, nothing will happen, also no error too

Comment: Yes I saw that before. You are using socket.getOutputStream there. It should be clientSocket.getOutputstream. Didn't I say that? If you now will try that then please adapt your code also so we can see what you are doing.

Comment: i update with logcat, but i cant understand why that arises nullPointer Exception, cos i do the same in client

Comment: Your `NullPointerExecption` is on `com.example.socketservereg.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:67)`. So what is on line 67? And why you still didn't change `socket.getInputStrem` to `clientSocket.getInputStream`? Or did you and is clientSocket null? Please tell more what you are doing as this becomes a very long story in this way.

Comment: if i change to clientSocket.getOutputStream(), that will also return the same error, means both clientSocket.getOutputStream() and socket.getOutputStream() will return same error.

Comment: What is `the same error` exactly? Please adapt your code here.

Comment: updated code and logcat, the only change is just replace 'socket.getOutputStream()' with clientSocket.getOutputStream() in onClick() method. it also produce nullPointer Exception, and still message from server not delivered

Comment: You have to do more than that. You had to add a private variable clientSocket to your class before it even would compile. And then you would have had to initialize it when a client connected. Moreover check for null as the user could click the button before there is a connection. Please add the relevant code.

Comment: all things are done, just forget to change the declaration. after accepting the request from client, paases though CommunicationThread, so i think there is no possibility to be null.

Comment: No. In your CommunicationThread you are not initialising that clientSocket but the one private to that class. Moreover in onClick you should really check for null like `if(clientSocket==null){Toast( ... no connection yet); return;}`.

Comment: sorry i am totaly new to android, can you please say how can i do that?

Comment: Are you asking about initialising or about the toast?

Comment: about initialisation, in thread it redeclared, is that the problem?

Comment: Yes. In your servercode. In class CommunicationThread. Remove declaration `private Socket clientSocket;`. In the same class: change `public CommunicationThread(Socket clientSocket)` to `public CommunicationThread(Socket aClientSocket)`. Change `this.clientSocket=clientSocket` to `clientSocket=aClientSocket`. Change the other `this.clientSocket` to `clientSocket` or `aClientSocket`.

Comment: now i got LogCat Error like "Socket closed" and clientApp get Forcefully closed

Comment: Please first adapt your code here so that it is what you have now. Second: post the logcat. But if the error now is in the client there is progress! Which socket was closed exactly? Of the client?

Comment: Please tell your setup: using devices or emulators?

Comment: updated the code of server. but i cant get the logcat of client, only server's and that doesnt have any problem. on client side emulator(i run both server and client in different emulator, first run server and then client, via port forwarding) gets a message "clientApp get Forcefully closed". i think client cant read message from socket

Comment: Don't know how that works with two emulators on a logcat. Only one visible? Then can you change server and client app emulator? Or start a new post where you ask how to obtain logcat from two emulators. Is the client code you posted here up to date? If not please do. I will have a look then.

Comment: In your client code statement `updateConversationHandler = new Handler();` is missing. Is that a typo? It would cause for a closing of app.

Comment: @greenapps i have same issue but fixed . my issue is only one client getting the message. I need send to all client