# How to send message from server to client (TCP , android applications)

Tags: android, sockets, tcp

I had created two android applications connected with sockets. Client sends an image to server and Server displays it. when you touch the image on server, it gets its coordinates,this is working now. what I need is that server sends the coordinates to the client, but I dont know how to send them to client and retrieve them, should I open a new socket ? I have no idea how to do this. Can somebody give me a hand please?

This is my code so far

SERVER

```
package com.example.serverlate;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ServerLate extends Activity {

    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    String touchedCoordinates;
    Handler updateConversationHandler;
    Thread serverThread = null;
    private ImageView imageView;
    public static final int SERVERPORT = 6000;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_server_late);

        imageView=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewServer);

        updateConversationHandler = new Handler();
        this.serverThread = new Thread(new ServerThread());
        this.serverThread.start();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        try {
            serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    class ServerThread implements Runnable {

        public void run() {
            Socket socket = null;
            try {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

                try {

                    socket = serverSocket.accept();
                    CommunicationThread commThread = new CommunicationThread(socket);
                    new Thread(commThread).start();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class CommunicationThread implements Runnable {

        private Socket clientSocket;
        private DataInputStream input;    
        public CommunicationThread(Socket clientSocket) {

            this.clientSocket = clientSocket;

            try {
                InputStream in = this.clientSocket.getInputStream();
                this.input = new DataInputStream(in);               
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void run() {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                try {
                    byte[] data;
                    int len= this.input.readInt();                  
                    data = new byte[len];                   
                    if (len > 0) {
                        this.input.readFully(data,0,data.length);
                    }   
                    updateConversationHandler.post(new updateUIThread(data));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    class updateUIThread implements Runnable {
        private byte[] byteArray;

        public updateUIThread(byte[] array){    
            this.byteArray=array;   
        }

        @Override
        public void run() { 
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray , 0, byteArray .length);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                touchedCoordinates="Touch coordinates : " +
                        String.valueOf(event.getX()) + " x " + String.valueOf(event.getY());
                    return true;
            }
        });
        }
    }
}
```

CLIENT

```
package com.example.clientlate;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ClientLate extends Activity {

    private Socket socket;

    private static final int SERVERPORT = 5000;
    private static final String SERVER_IP = "10.0.2.2";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_client_late);      

        new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        try {           
            ImageView imageView=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            Bitmap bmp=((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap(); 

            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
            bmp.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0 /*ignored for PNG*/, bos); 
            byte[] array = bos.toByteArray();

            OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream(); 
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(out);
            dos.writeInt(array.length);
            dos.write(array, 0, array.length);

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    class ClientThread implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);

                socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

            } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Your code looks very familiar to me. For the server to send unrequested messages you need a client wich always tries to read in a thread. See this post with nearly the same code where this got implemented:       http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24238234/server-cant-sent-message-to-client/24243178#comment37560183_24243178

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this in client side :

```
public class ClientLate extends Activity {
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     ....
    updateConversationHandler = new Handler();
    FPSHandler = new Handler();
    new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
    ....
}
class ClientThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        thread1=Thread.currentThread();
        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
            socketTE = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
            CommunicationThread commThread = new CommunicationThread(socketTE);
            new Thread(commThread).start();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection failed",
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        } catch (IOException e1) {              
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection failed",
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
    }

}

class CommunicationThread implements Runnable 
{

    private Socket clientSocket;
    private BufferedReader input;
    public CommunicationThread(Socket clientSocket) 
    {
        thread2=Thread.currentThread();
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
        try {
            this.input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    public void run() 
    {
        while (running.get()) 
        {
            try 
            {
                String read = input.readLine();
                updateConversationHandler.post(new updateUIThread(read));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

class updateUIThread implements Runnable 
{
    private String msg;
    public updateUIThread(String str) 
    {

        this.msg = str;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() 
    {       
            ...
    }
}
....
}
```